# Proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}2n\sin(\pi/n)r = 2\pi r$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}2n\sin(\pi/n)r = 2\pi r$$

Here's what I tried:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}2n\sin(\pi/n)r = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n*\pi/n*\sin(\pi/n)r}{\pi/n} = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\pi r*\sin(\pi/n)}{\pi/n}  = \\
2\pi r * \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\pi/n}
$$

Now I need to prove that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\pi/n} = 1$$

If we had $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. We could use squeeze theorem to prove that it equals 0. But clearly that is not true if $x=\pi/n$?

Comment: Is $x$ equal to $n$?

Comment: use $\sin t\sim t$ if $t\to 0$ and you get instantly the result

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes sorry I made a typo, it should be n and not x, fixed it now.

Comment: Your limit is $\lim_{x\to0}((\sin x)/x)$ if you let $x=\pi/n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Big thanks! As I understand x goes to zero when n goes to infinity, because we get $x=\pi/n = \pi/\infty = 0$